# Template Cast-Operator specification

Tags: c++

I'm setting up an Average class and fell over following problem:

```
template <typename T, typename Total>
class Average
{
public:
  Average(...){ ... }

...

operator double() const
{
  if (num_samples_ == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return static_cast<double>(total_) / num_samples_;
  }
}

operator T() const
{
  if (num_samples_ == 0)
  {
    return 0;
  }
  else
  {
    return round<T>(total_ / num_samples_);
  }
}
...
};
```

When I create the instance of Average like this:

```
Average<double, double> m_avg;
```

I get the error, that the operator double is already defined.

I understand that the operator is defined 2 times now. But how do I solve the problem? I want that the operator double() is called when double is casted and all other types call T()

Comment: Why do you need to have an explicit `operator double` conversion operator? Also note that conversion operators can lead to code that is harder to read, understand and maintain, especially if templates are involved.

Comment: Because I dont need to round in a double conversion

Comment: There is other (potential) problem in your code, not connected to your question. You return  zero as a "flag" that there are no samples... this implies that 'total_'  must be positive (assuming that num_samples_ is some kind of unsigned type). Are you ok with that?

Comment: I'm OK with that

Comment: I don't really see the need for the class here. Why not create a function which you can then specialize for `double`? Then you can also very simply overload these function to handle different data. Or why not go the standard library way and take a pair of iterators as arguments (defining a range of values), and then users can use whatever container of data that supports iterators.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your explicit question - you could make your first overload template and disable it for all other types than double by using of SFINAE mechanism. The template function has a lower priority than non-template overloads so it wouldn't match in case when T==double.

Exemplary code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct Foo {
    template <class D, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<D, double>, int> = 0>
    operator D() {
        std::cout << "double version" << std::endl;
        return 0.0;
    }

    operator T() {
        std::cout << "general version" << std::endl;
        return T{};
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo<double> fd;
    (double)fd;
    Foo<int> fi;
    (double)fi;
}
```

Output:

> ```
> general version 
> double version
> ```

[(Live demo)](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rwt5koG48hJSbCAy)

Note that if it need to be pre-c++17 use `typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<D, double>::value>::type` instead of `std::enable_if_t<std::is_same_v<D, double>, int>`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++2a, you may discard method thanks to `requires`:

```
operator T() const requires (!std::is_same<double, T>::value) {/*code*/}
```

Before that SFINAE on method (making it template) or (partial) specialization of the class might solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution not based on SFINAE:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct X {
  using T_ = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<T, double>::value, void, T>::type;
  operator double() { return double{}; }
  operator T_() { return T_{}; }
};

int main() {
  X<int> xi;
  X<double> xd;
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/vT4DTCWiEOkPWlhu